# Visio C# and EventSink

Tags: c#, event-handling, visio

I implemented an Windows form with eventsink to detect "shapeDeleted" once I just could access to

```
axDrawingControl1.Window.Shape.BeforeShapeDelete
```

I wanna to access to the "afterShapeDeleted", but right now I have two problems:

1- The below code do not work

```
pageEventList.AddAdvise((short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtCodeShapeDelete, eventHandler, "", "");
```

I'm  getting this error:

```
{"\n\nAn exception occurred."}
```

I already tried this(with no success):

```
pageEventList.AddAdvise((short)801, eventHandler, "", "");
```

2- The following code is working, but I don't know how can I return back to my form code to perform some extra code, once the detection is made at "EventSink.cs" class and not on my "Form.cs":

```
pageEventList.AddAdvise((short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtShape 
       + (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisEventCodes.visEvtDel, eventHandler, "", "");
```

There is anyway to catch the interruption on my Form.cs?

Thank you in advance,
Rodrigo Campos